# Access column array and store it in a new table

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a table like this:

```
| id | cars                     |      owner     |
|----|--------------------------|----------------|
|  1 | {tesla, bmw, mercedes}   | Chris Houghton |
|  2 | {toyota, bmw, fiat}      | Matt Quinn     |
```

Is there a way to access the car table array DISTINCT values and store them in a new table without duplicate values?

I want this table

```
| brands |
|--------|
|  tesla |
|  bmw   |
|mercedes|
| toyota |
|  fiat  |
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for this kind of statement.

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT 
  table_array.array_unnest
FROM (
  SELECT 
   UNNEST(cars)
  FROM 
   <table>
) AS table_array(array_unnest)
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56BDxiWuxNPVsg6gt1FRZ2/0)

> This indeed works but how can I store them for example in a column
>   "brand" of a table Manufactures.

```
INSERT INTO 
 Manufactures 
(brand)
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
    table_array.array_unnest
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      UNNEST(cars)
    FROM 
     <table>
  ) AS table_array(array_unnest)
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56BDxiWuxNPVsg6gt1FRZ2/0)

Comment: This indeed works but how can I store them for example in a column "brand" of a table Manufactures. Your solution only output the wright column.

Comment: Is there a way without using unnest because It gives me this error:   function unnest(character varying) does not exist

Comment: *"Is there a way without using unnest because It gives me this error: function unnest(character varying) does not exist –"* @vkatsou i advice upgrading to a more modern PostgreSQL version? Because it seams you are still running PostgreSQL 8.3?

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: @vkatsou PostgreSQL 8.3 simulate/emulate  [UNNEST](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Unnest) method, if you can't upgrade.